# Skyrim: Place lights in a House

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have bought Hjerim but it is a bit too dark at many locations. Is there anyway to places some light sources (candles/torches/lanterns etc) permanently in the house?

Torches turn off if dropped (it would have been better if I could fix them on walls) and pickable Lanterns don't have candles inside.

I don't mind using console to place light sources.

**EDIT:** I have bought all house upgrades, but light is still low.

**EDIT:**
*All I am interested is adding lights to existing original house. Putting torches in baskets or vases will work but it will be look more beautiful if you know a way to duplicate those candle stands, or the single candles (which are there on tables) or even lit lanterns.*

**UPDATE:** 
`placeatme 5d6e4` palces the burning Dwemer wall candle. It has less light but works.
[image]

Comment: found a link about decorating house with console but have no idea how to use it. http://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/477049-renovate-your-house-with-console/page__st__320

Comment: Have you bought any upgrades yet? They include more light sources.

Comment: Yes, I have bought all upgrades, but lights are still low

Comment: I think I used Sean Hutchensen's trick in this answer for using dropped torches.  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/46945/is-there-a-way-to-drop-a-lit-torch-in-my-house

Comment: Dropped torches look ugly, placing lights properly would look more beautiful

Comment: [Crafting PLUS](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/24209) adds craftable candles that are also movable light sources. I've only just discovered it and not had the time to try it, though, so that's just FWIW.

Comment: There's a mod that can make torches always lit: http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/10394 or you can equip a torch, drop it, exit cell, save game, load that save, re-enter cell, the torch will be lit. It's a nice trick to light up ur house

Comment: These guys say they have been putting torches in pots etc to make them look prettier. http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615803-/62873464

Comment: @BiffMaGriff Wrong thread? I just found http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615803-/61670166, which does mention the kettles and baskets.

Comment: I tried Better Hjerim mod which changed the house, but I am too scared to use the mods that change the game itself.

Comment: Putting torches in baskets is a good idea. I placed burning torches using `placeatme c82c7`

Comment: What is the object id of the curved candles , they are beautiful as well have a stand with them to put here and there

Comment: @BiffMaGriff I retract my previous statement; I didn't read the post properly.

Comment: @LifeH2O Whether my answer's accepted or not, I got to learn about some nice-looking mods, which I'll be installing when I get home; have some rep.

Comment: All I am interested is adding lights to existing original house. Putting torches in baskets or vases will work but it will be look more beautiful if you know a way to duplicate those candle stands, or the single candles (which are there on tables) or even lit lanterns.

Comment: @desaivv I don't use a mod that can do what OP would like as I actually prefer my Skyrim a bit darker (I use Realistic Lighting to make interiors a bit darker). Also, see [my reply to KBKarma's answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/88898/skyrim-place-lights-in-a-house#comment122973_89289).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the [**SM Drop Lit Torches** (PC)](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/10394) / [(Xbox One)](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/3049053) mod:

> This mod allows you to drop lit torches to the ground when you can't spare a hand to hold it.

You can combine this with a mod like [Double Torch Radius](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/9605) or [Torches for Realistic Lighting](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/8741) (but don't use Realistic Lighting as [it will make interiors darker](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/88898/skyrim-place-lights-in-a-house#comment122973_89289)), to increase the light radius of torches.

Then, just drop lit torches all over your house (good thing all houses in Skyrim are fireproof).

---

A [post (*Renovate your House with console*) in the Skyrim Nexus forums](http://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/477049-renovate-your-house-with-console/) has a detailed description of how to use console commands to add light sources and other items in your game. It includes form IDs of objects that you might want to put at your house.

<sup>(Thanks to kotekzot for [posting this link](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89567/skyrim-how-to-place-lit-candles-with-console?lq=1#comment123464_89567).)</sup>
Quoting a part of the post here:

> [Every FormID (item/object ID) (The best decorating categories are on the right.)](http://fusromod.com/formids.php)
> [Light FormIDs only](http://fusromod.com/formids.php?idpage=object_light)
>
> #### Basic Commands:
>
> **MarkForDelete** = Delete Object (Open Console, while in console use mouse to click the item you want to delete, leave and return to area or Quicksave/load for the item to actually go away.)
>
> **Help X 0** = Replace X with query (ex. Help Bed 0.) to find everything named bed and get the objects ID.
>
> **Placeatme X** = Replace X with Object ID (ex. Placeatme AF6AE.) Click a position while in console, will place the object there. (rarely works)
>
> **Player.placeatme X** = Same as above except places object directly below you. Look straight ahead for object to spawn straight.
>
> **TWF** = Wire frame to check clipping of objects.
>
> **TCL** = Fly to allow you to place objects in air or on wall.
>
> **Getpos x,y,z** = Gets the position of an object (ex. getpos z)
>
> **Setpos x,y,z #** = Sets the position of an object. (ex. setpos z 250 ) good used with getpos to take floors z axis, then set your objects z axis to be the same.
>
> **Getangle x,y,z** = Gets the angle of an object (ex. getangle z)
>
> **Setangle x,y,z #** = Sets the angle of an object. (ex. setangle z 245 )
>
> **Rotate x,y,z #** = Rotates the object manually. (ex. rotate z 245)
>
> **Setscale #** = Sets size of object.

Comment: Thank you. I posted the link to this forum post in first comment below my question (link is to the page where torches are mentioned).

Answer (score 5):

I've done some trawling. The best I can find is in [this GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615803-/61670166) thread, where user rampagingwalrus uses the lit torches method, but puts them into kettles to keep them out of the way (another user mentions using baskets for the same purpose). If you're short on torches, player.AddItem X Y (where X is either 1d4ec, 36343, or c82c7, and Y is the amount) will give you some.

Other than that, I think it's mod time. [Improved Interior Lighting (For Realistic Lighting Mods)](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=13434) allows for more realistic lighting in interior areas, and looks rather impressive. [Better Vlindrel Hall Lighting](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=73991180) specifically fixes Vlindrel Hall's lighting, while [Better Breezehome Lighting](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=74111353) fixes Breezehome's lighting, in both cases by adding new light sources. There's also [Torches for Realistic Lighting](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=9475) which makes torches more realistic by increasing all torches' light radius. Note that all of these either require or assume you're using [Realistic Lighting](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=7648), which makes some impressive changes. Finally, there's [Skyrim Enhanced Shaders fx - ENB](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/822), which improves the shaders and apparently adds lighting controls, but for some reason isn't on Steam Workshop. There's also [House Mods](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=15132), which improves all homes, and [Hjerim Improved](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=79429189), which specifically improves Hjerim, but they both change the houses a lot more than just adding light, and the latter seems to be incompatible with Hearthfire. Personally, the Realistic Lighting Mod(s) looks the way to go.

Comment: [Realistic Lighting](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/7654) will actually make interiors darker (how dark it is will depend on the options you chose - I don't think it has a "more lights" or a "brighter lights" option). Some of the things it changes are (from its [mod description](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/7654)):  *For interiors: Darker interiors (this will be improved for Realistic Lighting 4.0)*.

Comment: *desk+head* I didn't notice that. Still, as I said earlier, excellent mods, so something good's come out of it.

Comment: Realistic Lighting is indeed an excellent mod, and makes Skyrim look much better, IMO.

Answer (score 5):

On the PC, you can use the console to place any object anywhere. To position your new light sources perfectly, drag an object (default hold <kbd>E</kbd> over an item you can take) and move it where you would like your new light to be. Open the console and target the dragged item by clicking on it, then type "placeatme x" where X is the base ID of an object you would like to place.

Here's an except of a [list of some objects you can place with the console](http://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/477049-renovate-your-house-with-console/page__st__320) that are most relevant to you

- 1b410 Ruins wall sconce
- 1b061 Ruins ceiling sconce
- 19e25 Ruins floor sconce
- 6b36a Dwemer chandelier
- 5adea Dwemer floor sconce
- 30ad1 Dwemer wall sconce
- 5d6e4 Dwemer wall candle
- 30ad2 Dwemer chandelier Lg
- 8d5fb Dwemer incense burner

So to place a chandelier you would use "placeatme 6b36a".

Do note that once a light source has been added, it can never be removed - you will be able to target and disable the sconce or whatever light source you've used, but the light it gives off will remain. It is advisable to make a hard save before adding lights, as well as inspect how the new lights interact with the environment before making the changes permanent.

Comment: This looks like the most relevant answer.

Comment: 6b36a, 8d5fb, 30ad2 are just stands without lights
and 5d6e4 has light

Comment: 5adea , 30ad1 has no light

Comment: 5de64 is the most similar thing I was looking for

Comment: If anyone is still interested, click through to the list of objects; you can just place light without an object for it to come from. e.g. cd065 is the light of a fireplace.

Answer (score 0):

I found burning Candles, they do have light but it is too low to enlighten a place. You might have to add lights also.

Some of them are below, many others can be found on the 1st link below

- 7ea42 wall candle
- 5ad5b ceiling candle
- 5d6e4 dwemer wall candle

Sources:

http://steamcommunity.com/id/Shawkab/screenshots/?tab=public&
http://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/477049-renovate-your-house-with-console